# How to validate declarative schema

Tags: magento2, declarative-schema

In Firstname i don't want to insert special character and in email only insert valid email id

```
<table name="feedback" resource="default" engine="innodb" comment="mage2 tv example brand table" charset="utf8" collation="utf8_general_ci">
    <column name="feedback_id" xsi:type="int" padding="11" unsigned="true" identity="true" comment="Feedback Id" nullable="false"/>
    <column name="firstname" xsi:type="varchar" nullable="false" length="100" comment="First Name"/>
    <column name="lastname" xsi:type="varchar" nullable="false" length="100" comment="Last Name"/>

    <column name="description" xsi:type="text" nullable="true" comment="Brand Description"/>
    <column name="is_enabled" xsi:type="boolean" nullable="false" default="0" comment="Is the brand enabled?"/>
    <column name="weighting_factor" xsi:type="decimal" precision="5" scale="4" default="1" unsigned="false" nullable="false" comment="Search weighing factor"/>

    <column name="created_at" xsi:type="timestamp" default="CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"/>
    <column name="updated_at" xsi:type="timestamp" default="CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" on_update="true" nullable="false"/>

    <column xsi:type="smallint" name="website_id" padding="5" unsigned="true" nullable="false" identity="false"
            comment="Website Id"/>

    <constraint xsi:type="foreign" referenceId="MAGE2TV_DEMO_JS_WEBSITE_ID_STORE_WEBSITE_WEBSITE_ID" column="website_id" referenceTable="store_website"
                referenceColumn="website_id" onDelete="CASCADE"/>

    <constraint xsi:type="primary" referenceId="PRIMARY">
        <column name="id"/>
    </constraint>

    <constraint xsi:type="unique" referenceId="MAGE2TV_DEMO_JS_NAME">
        <column name="name"/>
    </constraint>

</table>
```

Comment: You have to implement your validation at model & service contact layer not at database layer

Comment: Actually i m confused how to implement it. can you please explain what should be procedure.